# How to reload RoR application page automatically when .erb file is modified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-chrome, automation, reload

Is there any simple way to reload RoR page in chrome after modifying `.erb` file?

I'm using VScode and Chrome browser. Rails version is `5.2.1` and ruby version is `2.4.0`.

I've tried using gems `guard` and `guard-livereload` and a livereload extension for Chrome browser and found they were not reload browser after modifying `erb` files. The extension seemes to be not maintained now.

I understand using webpack-dev-server makes automatic reload, however, in this Rails project I don't need webpacker.

Comment: you can press f5...

Comment: Keep in mind...saying something is "not working correctly" does not provide enough information to solve your particular problem. Instead, it seems like you are asking a broad question on how to implement auto reload, which may not be appropriate for this forum.

Comment: @MarkMerritt thanks for advice,  I should have been more careful. Fixing my question now.

Comment: @BradWerth　I'm sorry I didn't make it clear enough.  
 In this case pressing f5 every time is not "automatic browser refresh". I'd like to  achieve hot reload.

Comment: Can you share your `Guardfile`? `guard` is a nice solution for this but you might need `rack-livereload` too.